# How to wait for t32rem DO script to complete?

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

It seems that doing `t32rem localhost DO script.cmm` is non-blocking. How can I block in a shell script until the cmm script is done?

Here is an abbreviated example:

```
$ time t32rem localhost wait 5s
real    0m5.048s

$ cat wait-5s.cmm 
WAIT 5s
ENDDO    
$ time t32rem localhost do wait-5s
real    0m0.225s
```

I can try to do some sort of `t32rem localhost wait STATE.RUN()` based on whatever the exact script is doing but this is not a very good solution.

Reading through api_remote.pdf it does note that `T32_Cmd` for DO is non-blocking and recommends polling using `T32_GetPractice` but it's not clear how to translate this to `t32rem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you questions is a rather good one.

First the bummer: **t32rem** is not suitable to wait for the execution of a script. In fact t32rem cancels any running script before executing a command with T32_Stop(). (You can find the source code of t32rem in your TRACE32 installation at "C:\T32\demo\api\capi\test\t32rem.c")

So your suggestion to use `t32rem localhost wait STATE.RUN()` will definitely not work because it would cancel the running script. Furthermore `STATE.RUN()`returns the running state of the debugged CPU and not of the PRACTICE interpreter.

So in fact you have to use T32_GetPractice() to wait for the PRACTICE script to terminate. To use T32_GetPractice() you either have to link statically or dynamically the "API for Remote Control and JTAG Access in C" to an application that launches your script.

For dynamic linking (e.g. from a Python script) load "C:\T32\demo\api\capi\dll\t32api.dll". (Depending on your host operation system you might need t32api64.dll, t32api.so, or t32api64.so instead.)

For static linking (e.g. from a binary application written in C) add the files from "C:\T32\demo\api\capi\src" to your project.

And here is the code to write a command line application **t32do**, which starts a PRACTICE script and waits until the script terminates:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "t32.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int         pstate;
    const char *script;

    if (argc == 4  &&  !strncmp(argv[2],"port=", 5)) {
        if ( T32_Config( "PORT=", argv[2]+5 ) == -1 ) {
            printf("Port number %s not accepted\n", argv[2] );
            exit(2);
        }
        script = argv[3];
    } else {
        if (argc != 3) {
            printf( "Usage: t32do <host> [port=<n>] <script>\n" );
            exit(2);
        }
        script = argv[2];
    }
    if ( T32_Config( "NODE=", argv[1] ) == -1 ) {
        printf( "Hostname %s not accepted\n", argv[1] );
        exit(2);
    }
    if ( T32_Init() != 0 ||  T32_Attach(1) != 0){
        printf( "Failed to connect to TRACE32\n" );
        exit(2);
    }

    if ( T32_Cmd_f("DO \"%s\"", script) != 0 ){   // Launch PRACTICE script
        printf( "Failed to start PRACTICE script\n" );
        T32_Exit();
        exit(1);
    }
    while (T32_GetPracticeState(&pstate) == 0  &&  pstate != 0){   // Wait until PRACTICE script terminates 
        usleep(10000);
    }
    T32_Exit();
    return 0;
}
```

Put the source in a file named t32do.c in "C:\T32\demo\api\capi\src" and build the application with the following makefile, which works on both Windows (by using the MinGW compiler of Cygwin) and Linux:

```
BIN   := t32do
OBJ   := t32do.o hremote.o hlinknet.o

OS := $(shell uname -s)

ifneq ($(findstring CYGWIN,$(OS)),)
CC    := x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
LOPT  := -lws2_32
COPT  := -DT32HOST_LE
endif

ifneq ($(findstring Linux,$(OS)),)
CC    := gcc
COPT  := -DT32HOST_LE
endif

all: $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $^ -s -o $@  $(LOPT)

%.o: %.c t32.h
    $(CC) -c $(COPT) -o $@  $<

clean:
    -rm $(OBJ) $(BIN)
```

If it compiles and links fine, you'll get an application t32do.exe. 
Use it in the form: `t32do <host> [port=<n>] <practice script>`

My example code above is licensed under [Creative Commons Zero 1.0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/). Use it any way you wish, in any code you want.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the answer is "roll your own using t32api", it would be much better if the builtin t32rem tool handled this with an --option. I ended up writing something similar in python using ctypes instead of subprocess.run('t32rem DO').